# CakePHP Multiple Input Fields for one Column

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

I've tried to find some solutions to my problem but i either didnt search very well because i didnt know which keywords to use or the "solutions" didnt solve my problem.

I want to split up a normal textarea-field into single text-fields, so that each of this single-line text fields represents one line in the textarea-field. I would like that all of the content of these single-line text-fields will be saved together as one text, but seperated by a ';' character.

The concrete idea was, that the user can add 1-10 "positive" arguments and 1-10 "negative" arguments and I dont want to add 10 columns for each side in my table.

I'm relatively new to CakePHP and don't know how I can create such a special form. Has anyone an idea?

Here's my Controller code:

```
    public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Review->create();
        //Added this line
        $this->request->data['Review']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        global $textarea;
        if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
            $textarea = implode(';', $this->request->data['Review']['review_positive']);
        }
        if ($this->Review->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The review has been saved.'.$textarea));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The review could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my Model Code:

```
class Review extends AppModel {

/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var array
 */
public $validate = array(
    'review_body' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
        'Length' => array(
            'rule'    => array('between', 2700, 8200),
            'message' => 'Review muss zwischen 2700 und 8200 Zeichen haben'
        )
    ),
    'review_positive' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
        //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
        //'allowEmpty' => false,
        //'required' => false,
        //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
        //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
```

Here's my view code of the 'add'-view:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('review_body', array('label' => 'Review'));
            for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
                echo $this->Form->input('review_positive.'.$i, array('type'=>'text'));
            }
```

Here's my HTML Code of the "add Review"-view:

```
    <form action="/gr_1/reviews/add" id="ReviewAddForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"><div style="display:none;"><input name="_method" value="POST" type="hidden"></div> <fieldset>
        <legend>Add Review</legend>
    <input name="data[Review][user_ID]" value="1" id="ReviewUserID" type="hidden"><input name="data[Review][game_ID]" value="0" id="ReviewGameID" type="hidden"><div class="input textarea required"><label for="ReviewReviewBody">Review</label><textarea name="data[Review][review_body]" cols="30" rows="6" id="ReviewReviewBody" required="required"></textarea></div><div class="input text required"><label for="review_positive0"></label><input name="data[review_positive][0]" id="review_positive0" required="required" type="text"></div><div class="input text"><label for="review_positive1">1</label><input name="data[review_positive][1]" id="review_positive1" type="text"></div><div class="input text"><label for="review_positive2">2</label><input name="data[review_positive][2]" id="review_positive2" type="text"></div><div class="input text"><label for="review_positive3">3</label><input name="data[review_positive][3]" id="review_positive3" type="text"></div><div class="input text"><label for="review_positive4">4</label><input name="data[review_positive][4]" id="review_positive4" type="text"></div><div class="input text"><label for="review_positive5">5</label><input name="data[review_positive][5]" id="review_positive5" type="text"></div><div class="input text"><label for="review_positive6">6</label><input name="data[review_positive][6]" id="review_positive6" type="text"></div><div class="input text"><label for="review_positive7">7</label><input name="data[review_positive][7]" id="review_positive7" type="text"></div><div class="input text"><label for="review_positive8">8</label><input name="data[review_positive][8]" id="review_positive8" type="text"></div><div class="input text"><label for="review_positive9">9</label><input name="data[review_positive][9]" id="review_positive9" type="text"></div><div class="input textarea required"><label for="ReviewReviewNegative">Kontra</label><textarea name="data[Review][review_negative]" cols="30" rows="6" id="ReviewReviewNegative" required="required"></textarea></div><div class="input textarea required"><label for="ReviewReviewConclusion">Fazit</label><textarea name="data[Review][review_conclusion]" cols="30" rows="6" id="ReviewReviewConclusion" required="required"></textarea></div><div class="input number required"><label for="ReviewReviewValue">Wertung</label><input name="data[Review][review_value]" id="ReviewReviewValue" required="required" type="number"></div><input name="data[Review][review_rating]" value="0" id="ReviewReviewRating" type="hidden"><input name="data[Review][review_flags]" value="0" id="ReviewReviewFlags" type="hidden"><div class="input date required"><label for="ReviewReviewCreatedMonth">Review Created</label><select name="data[Review][review_created][month]" id="ReviewReviewCreatedMonth" required="required">
<option value="01" selected="selected">January</option>
<option value="02">February</option>
<option value="03">March</option>
<option value="04">April</option>
<option value="05">May</option>
<option value="06">June</option>
<option value="07">July</option>
<option value="08">August</option>
<option value="09">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>-<select name="data[Review][review_created][day]" id="ReviewReviewCreatedDay" required="required">
<option value="01">1</option>
<option value="02">2</option>
<option value="03">3</option>
<option value="04">4</option>
<option value="05">5</option>
<option value="06">6</option>
<option value="07">7</option>
<option value="08">8</option>
<option value="09">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22" selected="selected">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
</select>-<select name="data[Review][review_created][year]" id="ReviewReviewCreatedYear" required="required">
<option value="2034">2034</option>
<option value="2033">2033</option>
<option value="2032">2032</option>
<option value="2031">2031</option>
<option value="2030">2030</option>
<option value="2029">2029</option>
<option value="2028">2028</option>
<option value="2027">2027</option>
<option value="2026">2026</option>
<option value="2025">2025</option>
<option value="2024">2024</option>
<option value="2023">2023</option>
<option value="2022">2022</option>
<option value="2021">2021</option>
<option value="2020">2020</option>
<option value="2019">2019</option>
<option value="2018">2018</option>
<option value="2017">2017</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
<option value="2014" selected="selected">2014</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2010">2010</option>
<option value="2009">2009</option>
<option value="2008">2008</option>
<option value="2007">2007</option>
<option value="2006">2006</option>
<option value="2005">2005</option>
<option value="2004">2004</option>
<option value="2003">2003</option>
<option value="2002">2002</option>
<option value="2001">2001</option>
<option value="2000">2000</option>
<option value="1999">1999</option>
<option value="1998">1998</option>
<option value="1997">1997</option>
<option value="1996">1996</option>
<option value="1995">1995</option>
<option value="1994">1994</option>
</select></div> </fieldset>
<div class="submit"><input value="Submit" type="submit"></div></form>
```

Edit: I forgot to mention that I use cakePHP version 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know how to create forms with cake, you can try this:

In your view

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    echo $this->Form->input('opinions.'.$i, array('type'=>'text');
```

And after submit, in the controller, just concat those

```
public function thesubmitaction() {
    //all other code
   if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
       $textarea = implode(';', $this->request->data['TheModel']['opinions']);
   }
}
```

And that's it, you'll have the final string in `$textarea`.

I don't know what have you tried or how familiar you are with cake, so if you need me to clarify something, tell me.

Other option would be just to put a textarea and tell the user to put each "argument" on a line and then in the controller you replace the newlines with `;`.

Comment: I dont know how to implement that exactly. What to do with the textarea-variable? But even more important: the values entered to the "opinions"-forms doesnt get delivered to the controller. ive done print_r($this->request->data['Review']) and there is no value for the opinions saved, only the other normal fields. Do i need to change something in the model? The model is just a baked one so its created by crud and i only changed data validation

Comment: you mean in the "view"-html code? its empty, so when i print out 'h($review['Review']['review_positive'])' you dont get any value. I also forgot to mention that I use cakePHP 2.4. And yes, I want it to be saved in the "review_positive" column.

Comment: mmm, imposible you get an empty html, I'm testing the same thing and it works... would you rather continue this conversation on a chatroom and see if we can solve it there? this conversation is getting rather lengthy. Create a room and invite me if you want :)

Comment: man I'm also new to this site :D Havent seen the comment (it was hided) and I cant create a chat room because i dont have enough reputation...

Comment: @hardking True... well, I'm going to delete a few comments to avoid that "you are to chatty" warning. You could add the view html code to the question. I'm not referring to what you point out, rather what you get when you use "view page source" in the browser, just for the part of the form (it should be something like `<form><input>` etc etc. we'll have to do this until you have enough rep (or we solve this :) )

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I can't help but asking myself how would the edit function be since you'll have to load the ; separated data into n inputs??